# || operator not working as expected

Tags: go

What is going wrong here? I am 100% sure I am sending a HTTP POST request, but somehow the OR operator is not working as I am expecting. In the first example the server returns a 405 and in the second example the code continues executing.

**not working:**

```
if req.Method != http.MethodPost || req.Method != http.MethodDelete {
    http.Error(res, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    return
}
```

**working:**

```
if req.Method != http.MethodPost {
    http.Error(res, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    return
}
```

Comment: It seems you need to use '&&' - your condition is always TRUE

Comment: @tom12e - console.log your reg object and see what the Method property is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not something) OR (not something else mutually exclusive) is always going to be true isn't it?

If it is method post, it will not be delete and vice versa , you might want && ?

Answer (score 0):

Like Kenny Grant said, you might want to ponder about the logic. Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
// only allow POST or DELETE
if req.Method != http.MethodPost && req.Method != http.MethodDelete {
    http.Error(res, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
    return
}
```